# Shadowing a UITextview like a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I have searched apple's documentation and other posts on Stack Overflow, but I'm still having trouble adding a shadow to the inside of a UITextView. I would like to make it look like a UITextField. Here's the code that I've tried.

```
CALayer *frontLayer = self.frontField.layer;
[frontLayer setBorderColor:CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), nil)];
[frontLayer setBorderWidth:1];
[frontLayer setCornerRadius:5];
[frontLayer setShadowRadius:10.0];
CGSize shadowOffset = {0.0,3.0};
[frontLayer setShadowOffset:shadowOffset];
[frontLayer setShadowOpacity:1];
self.frontField.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off simple and try this:

```
[myTextView.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[myTextView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
[myTextView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[myTextView.layer setShadowRadius:0.3];
[myTextView.layer.masksToBounds = NO]; //<-- for UITextView!
```

to optimise performance also add:

```
view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myTextView.bounds].CGPath;
```

Then you can add your other properties back in 1 by 1 and see what is causing an issue for you.

Comment: I entered the code you provided, and it did not affect the view. It looks like a plain UITextView. Was it supposed to do that? I'm new at working with CALayers and the like, so I'm not sure how everything is supposed to work together.

Comment: This code works with a generic `UIView` but strangely not with a `UITextView`. I have no idea why. To solve your problem you can simply add the `UITextView` to a `UIView` of the same size and add the shadow to the `UIView` object.

Comment: I almost didn't use this code because for some reason it's rated very low. But it works perfectly!  tnx

Answer (score 0):

According to [25 iOS performance tips & tricks](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#shadowpath), adding shadow by setting shadowOffset is an expensive operation and affects performance.

> Core Animation has to do an offscreen pass to first determine the
>   exact shape of your view before it can render the drop shadow, which
>   is a fairly expensive operation.

You can use instead:

```
myTextView.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds] CGPath];
```